# Best way to handle multiple possible queries conditions on an index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have a application which stores documents created by users.  These documents have authors, creation dates.  The authors can have roles.  Additionally a given document may get tagged with keywords.  There are ~16K documents in the database, and a user may want to view the documents with any combination of this information as a limit.  For example, see all documents by a given author, or published in a given time window, or from authors in this role, etc (and any combination of these).

Is there a recommended best way to implement this?  In general I have passed the desired conditions in the params hash and then either used a complicated if ... elsif.... else.. to decode the passed conditions directly into different Model.find calls.  Alternatively, I will use a similar if sequence to construct the proper SQL conditions phrase and then use a single find call.

Both of these seem like hacks and there should be a better way to do it with named scopes, but I can't figure out a clean way to deal with the permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Ben Johnson's SearchLogic -- it's a gem that basically generates named scopes on the fly.

http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You only need to have one line of code with  `Model.find`.  Instead of using conditional logic to create multiple `find` calls use conditional logic to populate the `:conditions` hash which is passed into the `find` call.